# activate background event using shortcut key

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension where if user selects the item in any web page and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> then that highlighted text spelling should be altered. How do i do it? I have tried using background event page functionality where DOMContentLoaded is used so I can use the listener where there is two task, one is to find the highlighted text and another is listen for the event like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> and do the work of reversing the spelling of that highlighted text. However, when I select the text, that selected text is not displayed in console either.

I have tried the following way

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "RevText",
  "description": "Reverse the spelling of higlighted text",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "html/popup.html",
    "default_title": "click me"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ],
  "options_page": "html/options.html",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
}


function init() {
  textToHyperLink();
}

function textToHyperLink(event) {
  console.log(event);
  var text = "";
  if (window.getSelection) { // when selecting the text, the highlighted/selected text is not shown in console
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
    // show the popup with the name of highlighted text 
    console.log(text);
    alert(text);
  } else if (document.selection) {
      text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return text;
}

if(document.readyState === 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init);
} else {
    init();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Tried content_scripts as

```
{
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches" : ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js" : ["js/content.js"]
    }
]
}
}

function init(event) {
  console.log('event', event);
  alert('event');
}

document.addEventListener('keydown',init);
```

This way, the console does not log anything neither alert box is opened when I click on the text and hit random keys.

Comment: You can't override Ctrl-N in Chrome because it's a protected hotkey to open a new window. Also, make sure to read the extension architecture - the background page is a separate invisible page.

Comment: can you guide me with other hotkey, please?

Comment: Use a content script and `keydown` listener, there are many examples.

Comment: I have update with content_scripts and keydown listener which is not even logging in the console when i click the text and press any random keys.

Comment: After changing manifest.json you need to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page, and reload the web page to run the content script (it happens only during page load).

Comment: I did that. I got frustrated and open the youtube and found that the content script is working only in youtube page. How does that happen?I think i have to refresh the page as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164800/discussion-between-pri-and-woxxom).